# Got caucus badge for voting but I have never voted

Tags: support, badges

Surprised to find out on SO that I've just been awarded the [Caucus badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus) for voting 1 day ago in the election. But I have never yet voted on SO!

Why has this happened? Has my account been compromised? Weird system glitch?

Can I find out who I supposedly voted for?

Comment: I think you voted for me? Double check by hitting the up arrow next to my name ;)

Answer (score 11):

The Caucus badge is awarded for merely visiting the election page. It is not contingent on you voting, we have the [Constituent badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1974/constituent) for that.

You earn the Caucus badge if:

- You visit the election while it is active (any of the 3 phases)
- You have enough reputation *to be able* to vote.

You can earn it multiple times, once per election.

Comment: Ah thanks, confusion over!

Comment: @kanagavelu: The minimum rep can differ from election to election, from site to site. It is not a given it'll be 150 for other elections. For the previous [ServerFault election](http://serverfault.com/election/2) it was 300, for example. In other words, there is a *reason* I didn't mention a specific amount in my post. :-)